# can you review my python code and correct them? It's related with algorithm problem(implementation)

Tags: python, algorithm, implementation

in array(5,5)

```
(1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5) 
(2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4) (2,5) 
(3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4) (3,5) 
(4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4) (4,5) 
(5,1) (5,2) (5,3) (5,4) (5,5)
```

we start from (1,1) /
'L' means 'move to the left for 1' /
'R' means 'move to the right for 1' /
'U' means 'move to the upper side for 1 /
'D' means 'move to the down side for 1 /

If you put /
5 /
R R /
then you will get (1,3)

If you put /
5 /
R R D /
then you will get (2,3)

If you put /
5 /
R R D L /
then you will get (2,2)

But if you put /
5 /
R R U /
then you will get (1,3) instead (0,3) /
even though you put 'U'(go upper side), there is no way to go. /
So the answer is not (0,3), but (1,3) /

#------------------------------------------

```
n=int(input('insert n : '))

x,y=0,0

run=input('move plan : ').split()

for r in run:

    if r=='L':
        if y==0:
            continue
        else:
            y-=1

    elif r=='R':
        if y==n-1:
            continue
        else:
           y+=1
           
    elif r=='U':
        if x==0:
            continue
        else:    
            x-=1

    elif r=='D':
        if x==n-1:
            continue
        else:
            x+=1
    
    else:
        continue
print(x+1,y+1)
```

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Above is the correct code which runs well and I originally intended to materialize.
to get this code I tried many times to materialize codes.
Here is the code not runs well but I don't know what is the problem with this code below
.Can you correct the code to run smoothly?

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
n=int(input('insert n : '))
array=[[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
array[0][0]=1

run=input('move plan : ').split()

for r in run:
    for i,j in zip(range(n), range(n)):
        if r=='L' and array[i][j]==1:
            if j==0:
                continue
            else:
                array[i][j],array[i][j-1]=array[i][j-1],array[i][j]

        elif r=='R' and array[i][j]==1:
            if j==n-1:
                continue
            else:
                array[i][j],array[i][j+1]=array[i][j+1],array[i][j]
           
        elif r=='U' and array[i][j]==1:
            if i==0:
                continue
            else:    
                array[i][j],array[i-1][j]=array[i-1][j],array[i][j]

        elif r=='D' and array[i][j]==1:
            if i==n-1:
                continue
            else:
                array[i][j],array[i+1][j]=array[i+1][j],array[i][j]
    
        else:
            continue
for i in range(n):
    print(array[i])
```

---

```
"""
put
5
R R R U D D

out
3 4
"""
```

---

the problem is - as I run the code, it stops in position (1,2)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line makes no sense:

```
    for i,j in zip(range(n), range(n)):
```

- You already are looping over the moves, so no other (nested) loop should be needed: each move will just do *one* action.
- This loop will produce pairs of `i` and `j` having `i == j`. So it makes you walk the diagonal of the grid. There is no reason why you would do that.

You should just initialise `i` and `j` to zero *before* the outer loop starts, and then inside the `if` conditions you should update either `i` or `j` (or neither) depending on the move.

As a side remark: you decided to create the matrix and mark cells with 1. Having that matrix in memory can help to visualise the path that you have taken, but in the end it is not essential to the algorithm. In essence, you only need to keep track of the coordinates; and for debugging, you could output those instead of the matrix.

Comment: It a bit late accept your answer!☆